# Using while loop in a function to call it again in python

Tags: python, function, while-loop

I have written a function that ask the user for input and searches from a predefined dictionary, after showing the results the function ask the user to search again. I'm using while loop but my code is not correct somehow. Here is my code:

```
def second_option():
    search = input('Enter name of application to see if it is available in our database:')
    searched_service = {}
    for i, j in all_services.items():
        if search in j[0].replace(" ","").lower():
            searched_service[i] = j
    if len(searched_service) == 0:
        print('Course Not Found')
    elif len(searched_service) > 1:
        print('\n',len(searched_service), 'courses have been found:\n' )
        for key, value in searched_service.items():
            print('\nCourse ID: ' + key + '\nCourse Name: '+ value[0]+'\nCourse Price: ' + value[1])
    else:
        print('\n',len(searched_service), 'course have been found:\n' )
        for key, value in searched_service.items():
        print('\nCourse ID: ' + key + '\nCourse Name: '+ value[0]+'\nCourse Price: ' + value[1])
    while True:
        search_again = input('Do you want to search again (Y/N)?')
        if search_again == 'Y':
            second_option()
        elif search_again == 'N':
            menu()
            break
        else:
            print('Select Y for Yes or, N for No')
```

[I'm getting the following output everything seems fine but the last should be to enter name to search but I guess I'm stuck in the loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOeWv.png)

Comment: Please show all your code, like what the `menu()` method is. And please put the text of your error/problem  in your post, not an image.

Comment: better put all code in `while True` instead of running again `second_option()`. And when it select `N` then don't run `menu()` but only exit this function. Current code uses recursion and this can make problem to go back

Answer (score 0):

You may have problem because inside `second_option()` you run again `second_option()` - it is recursion. And when you exit last `second_option()` then it returns to previous `second_option()` and it looks like it didn't exit loop.

And similar problem can make `menu()` in `second_option()`. When you exit `menu()` then it will return to `second_option()`

You should run all in `while True` without running again `second_option()`.

And you should exit function to go back to menu.

---

Something like code below:

I reduced it also. If user selects `N` or lower `n` then it exits loop and it goes back to menu. And if user selects any other value or simply press only `Enter` then it assumes that user want to repeat it. This way I don't have to write `Y` (or `y`) to repeat it - it make life easier and it is popular method in many tools. I also use lower and upper char in `[Y/n]` because it is popular method to show that it will use `Y` as default value when you only press `Enter`. Upper char informs that it default answer.

```
def second_option():
    
    while True:

        search = input('Enter name of application to see if it is available in our database:')
        searched_service = {}
    
        for i, j in all_services.items():
            if search in j[0].replace(" ","").lower():
                searched_service[i] = j

        if len(searched_service) == 0:
            print('Course Not Found')
        elif len(searched_service) > 1:
            print('\n',len(searched_service), 'courses have been found:\n' )
            for key, value in searched_service.items():
                print('\nCourse ID: ' + key + '\nCourse Name: '+ value[0]+'\nCourse Price: ' + value[1])
        else:
            print('\n',len(searched_service), 'course have been found:\n' )
            for key, value in searched_service.items():
            print('\nCourse ID: ' + key + '\nCourse Name: '+ value[0]+'\nCourse Price: ' + value[1])
            
        search_again = input('Do you want to search again [Y/n]?')
        search_again = search_again.upper()

        if search_again == 'N':
            break    # exit loop
            #return  # or exit function
```

---

**EDIT:**

If you want to repeat only when user use upper `Y` then you need nested loop

```
def second_option():
    
    while True:

        search = input('Enter name of application to see if it is available in our database:')
        searched_service = {}
    
        for i, j in all_services.items():
            if search in j[0].replace(" ","").lower():
                searched_service[i] = j
        if len(searched_service) == 0:
            print('Course Not Found')
        elif len(searched_service) > 1:
            print('\n',len(searched_service), 'courses have been found:\n' )
            for key, value in searched_service.items():
                print('\nCourse ID: ' + key + '\nCourse Name: '+ value[0]+'\nCourse Price: ' + value[1])
        else:
            print('\n',len(searched_service), 'course have been found:\n' )
            for key, value in searched_service.items():
            print('\nCourse ID: ' + key + '\nCourse Name: '+ value[0]+'\nCourse Price: ' + value[1])
            
        while True:
            search_again = input('Do you want to search again (Y/N)?')
            #search_again = search_again.upper()
            
            if search_again == 'Y':
                break   # exit inner loop
            elif search_again == 'N':
                return  # exit function
            else:
                print('Select Y for Yes or, N for No')
```